# Get KML style in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I need access to extracted style attributes (e.g. fill color, stroke color, etc.) for a KML file once loaded. I can't seem to find a way to access the style once the layer has been added. The myLayer.getStyle() returns a function as expected but how does one access the style attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You get the styles by calling the function.

As the [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/apidoc/ol.style.html#.StyleFunction) say, you should pass an ol.Feature object and a resolution value.
But it seems to return something also when you leave the parameters undefined.

```
var styleFn = myLayer.getStyle();
console.log(styleFn());
```